# why my selection sort is giving segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, output, selection-sort

help please can anybody point what is wrong with the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "enter the size of array ";
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    cout << "enter numbers  \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; i < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[i]) {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "the numbers are\n" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cout << arr[j] << " " << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is why is this code is not sorting the array and also not giving the output after taking input it is also showing segmentation fault?

Comment: Did you try running it with a debugger? You would see where the fault occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Take a **close** look at this for loop

```
for(int j=i+1;i<n;j++)
```

It's a simple typo.

I recommend adding a few spaces to your code, it makes it much easier to read and to spot mistakes like this

```
for (int j = i + 1; i < n; j++)
```

Better?